# Why Information is Null when Clicking Button first-time?

Tags: flutter, dart

**Solved:**
**please check my own answer..It's working well..but Is that proper way to fix like this issue?**

This is the registration details page. First-row display text-form-field and then dropdown and etc. User typing value and select dropdown and click button information value are `showing`. But user select dropdown value and then typing information and click the button, information value is `null`.

**AND ALSO typing value on textFormField and click button first time value is `null`, then click again button value is `showing`.** Why is that?

> I added `print('textfield is $details'),` in onPressed() method. 
>   scenario 1: typing information and click button value is `null`
>   scenarion 2: typing information and select dropdown/tap on screen and
>   click button value is `showing`

```
class _overview3 extends State<overview3> {
  final detailsController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: overviewAppBar(
            detailsController.text),
        body: Scaffold(

            body: Container(
                child: Container(
                    child: Scaffold(
              body: ListView(
                children: <Widget>[
                        TextFormField(
            controller: detailsController,
            maxLength: 100,
            maxLines: 2,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
            validator: (value) {
              if (value.length > 3) {
                return '100 values';
              }
            },
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              hintText: AppTranslations.of(context).text("additional_details"),
            ),
          ),
                ],
              ),
            )))
            ));
  }
```

in my OverviewAppBar method,

```
  overviewAppBar(String details) =>
    AppBar(
      brightness: Brightness.dark,
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFE27023),
      centerTitle: true,
      title: appBarIcon(context),
      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
            icon: _isButtonDisabled
                ? Icon(
                    Icons.check,
                    color: Colors.white30,
                  )
                : Icon(Icons.check),
            onPressed: () => _isButtonDisabled
                ? null
                : globals.isButtonClick
                    ? null
                    :{FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode()),
              print('textfield is $details')
}
)
]
);
```

[image]

Comment: please put some code sample of your issue

Comment: sorry, I edited

Comment: Can you add your log

Comment: @MangaldeepPannu can you understand my question, sir? because my English is not good... Why information showing, first typing additional information and then click the dropdown and then click the button?

Comment: @MangaldeepPannu i edited my question, please read yellow area

Comment: Can you you full code for screen.

Comment: @MangaldeepPannu added

Comment: AND ALSO typing value on textFormField and click button first time value is null, then click again button value is showing.

Comment: @MangaldeepPannu please check my own answer..It's working well..but Is that proper way to fix like this issue?

Comment: Honestly i didn't understand your issue. But glad to see you solved it. Also I don't see any issue in your approach.'

Answer (score 0):

**global.dart file**

```
final globalDetailsController = TextEditingController();
```

**in textformfield**

```
 TextFormField(
            controller: global.globalDetailsController
)
```

**in OverviewAppBar method in onPressed()**

```
  print('textfield is ${global.globalDetailsController}')
```